# How to implement fetch API by search

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a search bar. when I enter the name of any film, filtered data has to be displayed (as a result of fetching from API)

```
function App() {
  const [films, setFilms] = useState([])
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')
  const [filteredRes, setFilteredRes] = useState([])

  const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=KEY&s=${searchText}`
  useEffect (()=> { 
    loadData()
  }, [searchText])

   const loadData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(url)
   
    setFilms(res.data.Search)
    const filtered = await films.filter(i => i.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))
    setFilteredRes(filtered)

   }

   const onTextChange = (e) => {
     setSearchText(e.target.value)
   }
   

  return (
    <>
        <Container>
            <h1>Bookstore</h1>
            <Row>
            <form>
            <input type='text'
                   placeholder='Search...'
                   name="searchText"
                   onChange={onTextChange}
                   value={searchText}
                 
            />
           
               </form>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              { filteredRes.map(item => {
                return ( 
                
                  <Col lg={3} md={3} sm={12} key={item.imdbID}>
                   <img src={item.poster}/> 
                   <h6>{item.title}</h6>
                   <h6>{item.year}</h6>
                  </Col>

                )
              })}
        
            </Row>
        </Container>
      
    </>
  );
}
```

I have am issue:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. But why if I save fetched films in const [ films ] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ooutput:**

[image]

You don't have to filter fetched data additionally, the data that is being fetched by Axios is already filtered according to the `serchText` so Axios call does the all.

Full Example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const APIKEY = "your api";
export default function App() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!searchText) {
      alert("Please enter movie name");
      return;
    }
    Axios.get(
      `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=${APIKEY}&s=${searchText}`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setFilms(response.data.Search);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          placeholder={"Search movie"}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSearchText(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>

      {films.map((film) => (
        <div>
          <img src={film["Poster"]} alt={film["Title"]} width={100} />
          <p>{film["Title"]}</p>
          <p>{film["Year"]}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/TheKetan2/movie-app-react-starckoverflow-answer)

Comment: ok. thank you. but I have another issue. data that I fetch (looking for) returns an empty array in console.

Comment: but when I insert your url address, console shows 401 status code and it's said that I'm an unauthorized

Comment: one more, don't run it on code sandbox or other online editors, I was getting a network error when I tried to run this app from Codesandbox and also from Stackblitz, So I ran it on a local machine and it worked fine.

Comment: ok, now it works but strange.. 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
I did same way you did

Comment: I map through films

Comment: use conditional rendering then ```{films?.map((film) => (
        <div>
          <img src={film["Poster"]} alt={film["Title"]} width={100} />
          <p>{film["Title"]}</p>
          <p>{film["Year"]}</p>
        </div>
      ))}```

Comment: now no errors but data is displayed only in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225478/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and--).

Comment: fixed it, now it works! thank you to the moon and back:)

Comment: Awesome, happy coding :)

Comment: one more suggestion, if you are trying to deploy then change URL to ```https://www.omdbapi.com/....``` instead of ```http://www.omdbapi.com/...``` one.